# How to get the url parameters using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routeparams

HTML source code

```
<div ng-app="">
    <div ng-controller="test">
      <div ng-address-bar browser="html5"></div>
      <br><br>
      $location.url() = {{$location.url()}}<br>
      $location.search() = {{$location.search('keyword')}}<br>
      $location.hash() = {{$location.hash()}}<br>     
      keyword valus is={{loc}} and ={{loc1}}
  </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS source code

```
<script>
function test($scope, $location) {
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.ur = $scope.$location.url('www.html.com/x.html?keyword=test#/x/u');
  $scope.loc1 = $scope.$location.search().keyword ;    
    if($location.url().indexOf('keyword') > -1){    
        $scope.loc= $location.url().split('=')[1];
        $scope.loc = $scope.loc.split("#")[0]        
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Here the variables `loc` and `loc1` both return *test* as the result for the above URL. Is this the correct way?

Comment: You may want to check out [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeParams).

Comment: Not clear what you're asking here... the $routeParams and $location#methods docs should get you started

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 320):

I know this is an old question, but it took me some time to sort this out given the sparse Angular documentation.  The **RouteProvider** and **routeParams** is the way to go.  The route wires up the URL to your Controller/View and the routeParams can be passed into the controller.

Check out the [Angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project.  Within the app.js you'll find an example for the route provider.  To use params simply append them like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',    
    controller: 'MyCtrl1'
});
```

Then in your controller inject $routeParams:

```
.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  var param1 = $routeParams.param1;
  var param2 = $routeParams.param2;
  ...
}]);
```

With this approach you can use params with a url such as:
"http://www.example.com/view1/param1/param2"

Comment: Note that the last line of this example ```});``` should be ```}]);```

Comment: Also can get other arbitrary params in the query string form `/view/1/2?other=12` with  `$routeParams.other`

Comment: I think you have the 'var param1' repeated in your controller. I could not edit such a simple change.

Comment: Angular make it so easy, and also your answer is so nice descriptive

Comment: Assign and send example: var param1 = "abc"; $location.path('/view1/:' + param1);$route.reload();

Comment: Great for when you have multiple front-end routes, overkill if you just want to parse params.

Answer (score 169):

While routing is indeed a good solution for application-level URL parsing, you may want to use the more low-level `$location` service, as injected in your own service or controller:

```
var paramValue = $location.search().myParam;
```

This simple syntax will work for `http://example.com/path?myParam=paramValue`. However, only if you configured the `$locationProvider` in the HTML 5 mode before:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Otherwise have a look at the http://example.com/#!/path?myParam=someValue "Hashbang" syntax which is a bit more complicated, but have the benefit of working on old browsers (non-HTML 5 compatible) as well.

Comment: it seems like you have to add $locationProvider.html5mode(true) as a module config like so: angular.module("myApp", []).
    config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

Comment: And html5Mode requires a `<base href="http://example.com/en/" />` tag in your `index.html`.

Comment: what I like about your solution is that you can even pass objects, and you get them as object.

Comment: It's also possible to not add the <base> tag and specify it like this:
`.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
}])`

Comment: In Angular 1.5.8, I did not have to configure `$locationProvider` in order for this to work.

`http://example.com/path#?someKey=someVal`, then

`$location.search().someKey // => 'someVal'`

Answer (score 32):

If you're using ngRoute, you can inject `$routeParams` into your controller

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

If you're using angular-ui-router, you can inject `$stateParams`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: For `$stateParams` to show query parameters, I had to specify them when defining the states, as shown in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters

Answer (score 14):

I found solution how to use $location.search()  to get parameter from URL

first in URL u need put syntax " # " before parameter like this example

`"http://www.example.com/page#?key=value"`

and then in your controller u put $location in function and use $location.search() to get URL parameter for

```
.controller('yourController', ['$scope', function($scope, $location) {

     var param1 = $location.search().param1; //Get parameter from URL

}]);
```

Comment: Its works for query parameters and the below answer of @jeff is for path variables

Answer (score 2):

If the answers already posted didn't help, one can try with
$location.search().myParam; 
with URLs http://example.domain#?myParam=paramValue

Comment: That's the second highest voted solution on here... And posted 3 years before this one... https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481865/3578036

Answer (score 2):

```
function GetURLParameter(parameter) {
        var url;
        var search;
        var parsed;
        var count;
        var loop;
        var searchPhrase;
        url = window.location.href;
        search = url.indexOf("?");
        if (search < 0) {
            return "";
        }
        searchPhrase = parameter + "=";
        parsed = url.substr(search+1).split("&");
        count = parsed.length;
        for(loop=0;loop<count;loop++) {
            if (parsed[loop].substr(0,searchPhrase.length)==searchPhrase) {
                return decodeURI(parsed[loop].substr(searchPhrase.length));
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: window.location.href is actually what I needed in my case. Doesn't always have to be some fancy Angular solution. This didi the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and easist way to get url value**

```
First add # to url (e:g -  test.html#key=value)

url in browser (https://stackover.....king-angularjs-1-5#?brand=stackoverflow)

var url = window.location.href 

(output: url = "https://stackover.....king-angularjs-1-5#?brand=stackoverflow")

url.split('=').pop()
output "stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 0):

**When using angularjs with express**

On my example I was using angularjs with express doing the routing so using $routeParams would mess up with my routing. I used the following code to get what I was expecting:

```
const getParameters = (temp, path) => {
  const parameters = {};
  const tempParts = temp.split('/');
  const pathParts = path.split('/');
  for (let i = 0; i < tempParts.length; i++) {
    const element = tempParts[i];
    if(element.startsWith(':')) {
      const key = element.substring(1,element.length);
      parameters[key] = pathParts[i];
    }
  }
  return parameters;
};
```

This receives a URL template and the path of the given location. The I just call it with:

```
const params = getParameters('/:table/:id/visit/:place_id/on/:interval/something', $location.path());
```

Putting it all together my controller is:

```
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope, $window) {
  const getParameters = (temp, path) => {
    const parameters = {};
    const tempParts = temp.split('/');
    const pathParts = path.split('/');
    for (let i = 0; i < tempParts.length; i++) {
      const element = tempParts[i];
      if(element.startsWith(':')) {
        const key = element.substring(1,element.length);
        parameters[key] = pathParts[i];
      }
    }
    return parameters;
  };

const params = getParameters('/:table/:id/visit/:place_id/on/:interval/something', $window.location.pathname);
}]);
```

The result will be:

```
{ table: "users", id: "1", place_id: "43", interval: "week" }
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

in your router:

```
url: "/login/reset_password/:user/:token"
```

in your controller:

```
let userParam = $state.params.user
let tokenParam = $state.params.token
```