# AngularJS: How to pass arguments to controller when it is registered？

Tags: angularjs

Say I have a controller:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', Com.Xyz.ModuleHome.HomeController);
```

`Com.Xyz.ModuleHome.HomeController` is a controller function which has parameters like `$scope`, `$window`, `$timeout`, `$http`, ... these parameters are injected by AngularJS.

But I want to pass some parameters to the controller when it is registered. This is because my controllers are loaded from different domains by RequireJS, now I want to a controller to know where itself is from.

```
var myVar = jsFileUrl;  // jsFileUrl is provided by RequireJS

// I wish the code looks like below
app.controller('HomeCtrl', Com.Xyz.ModuleHome.HomeController, myVar);

// AngularJS will inject a $controllerContext representing controller itself
function Com.Xyz.ModuleHome.HomeController($controllerContext, $scope) {
    $scope.controllerJsFileUrl = $controllerContext.Argument;     
}
```

Is it possible? Maybe there is something I didn't know.

I know a service can do it, but I don't want the controller to depend on a special service name. In the future I may move the controllers to somewhereelse.

Comment: This might be helpul: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18191623/1488993

Comment: Why try to go against the framework? Dependency injection is a great thing. Perhaps your design could be reworked :)

Comment: No, I'm not against the framework. I just wish to get more information about the controller itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for the anti-pattern, you could try using `function.bind`and pass the argument in the bound function. This will let the value of myVar to be passed in as first argument when the constructor is invoked (everytime).

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', Com.Xyz.ModuleHome.HomeController.bind(null, myVar));
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
var myVar = 1234;



function Ctrl(myVar, $q, $http) {
  console.log(arguments);
}


app.controller('ctrl', ['$q', '$http', Ctrl.bind(null, myVar)]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```

The above approach  though short is tricky because you can no longer use controller instance as `this` as it would not the controller instance anymore instead it would be window. Another way is to create a dummy wrapper for the controller and new up the actual constructor.

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
    return new Ctrl(myVar, $q, $http);
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Learned something I don't know. :)

Comment: @Zach You are welcome. But you need to be careful doing this if you are using controller instance `this` as it wont be the instance instead would be global context.

Comment: I just tested, however, other parameters, e.g. $scope are undefined. I use the static injection:  $inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$window', '$timeout'];

Comment: @Zach that is another caveat you cant use $inject as well, it will work only with array annotation.

Comment: Thank you any way. But I just don't want to repeat the parameters of the function.