# How to extract query parameters with ui-router for AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, query-string, angular-ui-router

How do I extract query parameters using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for AngularJS?

In AngularJS' own `$location` service I did:

> ($location.search()).uid

to extract the parameter uid from a URL. What is the corresponding code for ui-router?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js

Comment: Thanks, but no. That answer relates to Angular's built-in routing. I'm using ui-router (link above) for *nested* routing.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Unless you're binding to the query parameters (see the documentation), you don't access them directly through `$state` or `$stateParams`. Use the `$location` service.

**EDIT:** Per [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters), if you want to capture query parameters in `$stateParams`, you can append a `?` to your `url`, and name each query parameter, separated by `&`, i.e. `url: "/foo?bar&baz"`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure if that was the way to go.

Comment: @Nate Abele  how would you bind to the query parameters. In my case, i'm building a view that filters a table of records, so a users types in a value in a text field, this value should be a query parameter so that the filter results can be linked to.

Comment: @mtpultz The docs only say what _to_ do, not what _not_ to do.

Comment: @MarkAlanEvans Updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Now, what if I don't don't have a pattern for my query strings, but still want to harvest that data? Like if you had a URL with the same pattern of an OData call with filters and such?

Answer (score 104):

See the query parameters section of the [URL routing documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters).

> You can also specify parameters as query parameters, following a '?':
>
> ```
> url: "/contacts?myParam"
> // will match to url of "/contacts?myParam=value"
> ```

For this example, if the url is `/contacts?myParam=value` then the value of `$state.params` will be:

```
{ myParam: 'value' }
```

Comment: For query parameters you really have to use `$state.params` as it is written in the answer. Not `$stateParams` which I used and didn't work.

Comment: @thisgeek when i used url: "/verifyMail?username" i got $state.params with empty value

Comment: same as @AnushaNilapu...this was working before, but its no longer working for me

Answer (score 10):

ui-router does not differentiate between different types of parameters in a url like the $location service does.

In your controllers you can use the $stateParams service to get access to all the different types of parameters in your url.

below is an example from the ui-router wiki:

```
// Then you navigated your browser to:
'/users/123/details/default/0?from=there&to=here'

// Your $stateParams object would be
{ id:'123', type:'default', repeat:'0', from:'there', to:'here' }
```

So in your case to find the uid param simply use:

```
$scope.uid = $stateParams.uid
```

Answer (score 9):

You also need to define the query parameters in the $stateProvider e.g.

```
state('new-qs', {
  url: '/new?portfolioId&param1&param2',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
     $scope.param1 = $stateParams.param1;
     $scope.param2 = $stateParams.param2;
  }
})
```

as explain by [benfoster.io](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from $stateParams , but in that case you have to declare the query variable in the route as well.

declare in route like -

```
url: '/path?name'
```

for getting name in controller inject $stateParams , 
and use like -

`$stateParams.name`

Answer (score 0):

For recent versions of AngularJS and ui-router I think that you can just use `$state` to access the params:

```
$state.params[<PARAMETER_NAME>]
```

where in app.js you defined the state as follows:

```
.state('app.name', {
    url: '/:some_param_id',
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html'
})
```