# Simplest way to pass value from url to the content of page in ionic framework using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework for developing my hybrid mobile application and I have to access a content editing page where I need to pass in some values. For this, I have added the parameters in the url in routes.js routing file

```
.state('editText', {
    url: '/editText/:id/:text/:size',
    templateUrl: 'editText.php',
    controller: 'editTextCtrl'
  })
```

Now I want to access :id , :text and :size in the content of the page. Can I simply do it by using {id} , {text}, {size} in the content of page or do I need to do something else to make it happen. Please note that at this point I am looking for the fastest and simplest solution to achieve this without caring for security.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract query parameters with ui-router for AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053991/how-to-extract-query-parameters-with-ui-router-for-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can request the URL state parameters using `$stateParams`. Make sure you inject this into your controller.

Let's say you state url is `/editText/:id/:text`, then you can request the values from the url in your controller (`editTextCtrl`) using `$stateParams.id` and `$stateParams.text`.

Answer (score 0):

change your state as follows,

```
 .state('editText', {
        url: '/editText',
        templateUrl: 'editText.php',
        controller: 'editTextCtrl',
        params: {
            id:'',
            text:'',
            size:''
        }
      })
```

You can call the state from controller as follows to pass the parameters,

```
$state.go('editText',{id:45,text:'some text',size:45});
```

Then you can get these parameters in the  controller as follows,

```
.controller('editTextCtrl',['$stateParams',function($stateParams){
    console.log($stateParmas.id);
    console.log($stateParmas.text);
    console.log($stateParmas.size);
}]);
```

Comment: He shouldn't have to change his state