# UI Router and query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, query-string

I built a small search app using Angular, UI Router and Elasticsearch and I'm trying to get UI Router query parameters in the url on the results page.

I'm trying to achieve this

```
domain.com/search?user_search_terms
```

with this

```
.state('search', {
        url: '/search?q',
```

and I init searchTerms and $stateParams like this in my controller

```
vm.searchTerms = $stateParams.q || '';
```

and then in my search function in my controller I have this

```
 vm.search = function() {
          $state.go('search', {q: vm.searchTerms});
...
```

Everything works fine, until I try to implement the UI Route query parameters. I can still get search suggestions, transition from state to state but search breaks.

I thought I needed to implement Angular $http get params within a config {}, but then I realized I'm JUST trying to get query parameters using UI Router. It seems I have everything setup right with UI Router to get query parameters but ... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For query parameters, you should use **`$state.params`** instead of `$stateParams`

**STATE CONFIG:**

```
stateProvider.state({
    name: 'search',
    url: '/search?q',
    //...
}
```

**CONTROLLER FROM:**

```
function fromCtrl ($state) {
    $state.go('search', {q: vm.searchTerms});
}
```

**OR TEMPLATE/HTML LINK FROM:**

```
<a ui-sref="search({q:'abc'})">my Link</a>
```

**CONTROLLER TO:**

```
function toCtrl ($state) {
    this.searchTerms = $state.params.q;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** use `$transition$` for new versions >= 1.0.0 ([PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZFGntE4FORWPEzZQaoZH?p=preview))

The code above is the same for both versions, only you need to change the `toCtrl`...

```
function toCtrl ($transition$) {
  this.myParam = $transition$.params().q;
}
```

---

*If your searchTerms is an object, you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`*

Check these posts if you still have any doubts:

[How to extract query parameters with ui-router for AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053991/how-to-extract-query-parameters-with-ui-router-for-angularjs)

[AngularJS: Pass an object into a state using ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632255/angularjs-pass-an-object-into-a-state-using-ui-router)