# is there routeParams functionaly in ui-router in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

When I use ngRoute I can get all params and queryParams such search and sectionId:

```
// Given:
// URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
// Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
//
// Then
$routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}
```

But when I use angularjs ui-route I have stateParams which not give me the all the data like routeParams give me.

Is there another service i can use to get all the data like routeParams does?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) will help you

Answer (score 0):

try with `$state.params`. value should be:

```
{ search:'moby' }
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053991/how-to-extract-query-parameters-with-ui-router-for-angularjs