# Read url requested in Angular app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When a page loads, I want to determine what url was used to load that page and intercept it in the controller so I can extract the parameters from it.

For example if http://mypage.com/#/myPage/otherStuff

How can I intercept this URL before the page loads?

Thank you.

(Use case)
1. user requests my page
2. I intercept, take out the parameters from the url
3. I format the page to match their parameters.

Comment: Popular question, I am sure the answers will be helpful: [How to get the url parameters using angular js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [these events (read the docs here).](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#events)

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {

});
```

From reading the comments, I see that your question is an X/Y issue. My answer deals with your question of intercepting the url in the controller, but it looks like your overall goal is better accomplished by other means.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using either [ngRoute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/README.md) to define your route and make the variable parts of the uri into route parameters, which would then be available in your controller function.