# Angular - Return ID from URL Path in Controller

Tags: angularjs, url

I am building a rather simple AngularJS app, but for simplicity's sake, I'd rather not use the routing (if possible), and just serve back individual Angular pages from the server. Essentially, use Angular only for layout and functionality of 'widgets' and not for moving between pages.

With that said, I've spent hours trying to get an ID out of the current URL, so:

```
/Tickets/:id
```

All I want to do in my controller, is get the ID from the URL, then pass that to a Factory. (below is an example using pseudocode)

```
app.controller('ticketController', ['$scope', '$route',
    function ($scope, $route, $location) {
        //Get ID out of current URL
        var currentId = someFunction().id;
        factory.callFactory(ID);
    }]);
```

I've also tried creating routes, but the objects returned don't seem to provide a way to get the ID.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/tickets/:id',
      {
          templateUrl: '/partials/edit',
          controller: 'ticketController'
      }
    );
}]);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[This doesn't seem to work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js)

[This also doesn't seem to work, but I may be doing something wrong](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Answer (score 45):

Try `$routeParams` instead:

```
app.controller('ticketController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
   function ($scope, $routeParams) {
      //Get ID out of current URL
      var currentId = $routeParams.id;
}]);
```

Comment: You need to install ngRoute for this to work: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: How can I get it if I use $location.path("/products/" + category.id); ?

Answer (score 18):

If you are using `ui-router` so try `$stateParams`:

```
app.controller('ticketController', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
   function ($scope, $stateParams) {
      //Get ID out of current URL
      var currentId = $stateParams.id;
}]);
```

Comment: How can I get it if I use $location.path("/products/" + category.id); ?