# routePrams in angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJs . I am creating an app in which I passed the UserID in URL then trying to get the ID in the Js file using Routeparam but it is not working.I am Using MVC 4 and angularjs.
please see my code

My URL **/Home/GetUserInformation?userID=44**. I want userID in the below code

```
 var userInformationApp = angular.module('UserInformationApp', ['ngResource'])
    .config(function config($routeProvider, $stateProvider)
    {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider.
            when('/Home/GetUserInformation?userID=:ID',
            {
                templateUrl: "UserInformation.cshtml",
                controller: "UserInformationController"

            })


    angular.module('UserInformationApp', []).controller("UserInformationController", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http)
    {
        debugger;-----// My debugger is not hitting when I used routeParams.If I remove Route params Then it is working fine but route params then come undefined.

        $scope.saveNote = function ()
        {
            $scope.newNote = $scope.userNote;
            $scope.intialValue = true;
            $scope.record = $routeParams.ID;///// This I saw in net to get the ID or information from the URL in angular js.

        }

    });
```

When I am using RouteParams My Debugger is not hitting.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of getting parameters in a url: with `$routeParams` and manually.

**Angular way**

The normal way in angular is `$routeParams` :

```
when('/Home/GetUserInformation/:userid',
```

and now it is available in the controller:

```
$scope.record = $routeParams.userid
```

Some tutorials

- [Angular Tutorals: Multiple Views, Routing and Layout Template](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)
- [Mapping AngularJS Routes Onto URL Parameters And Client-Side Events](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm)
- [How to get the url parameters using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js)

**Query String**

Alternatively, you can also get the parameters in the query string manually.

If you know the name of the parameter:

```
$location.search().yourparam
```

and if you have an arbitrary number of parameters and  you don't know their names (e.g. to init the app's settings):

```
var queryString = $location.absUrl().match(/^[^?]+\??([^#]*).*$/)[1];
var items = queryString.split("&");
var params = {};

for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    var temp = items[i].split("=");
    if (temp[0]) {
        if (temp.length < 2) {
            temp.push("");
        }
        params[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working.Actually when I am using $routeParam in the Controller my flow breaking.It is not going inside the Controller function

Comment: can you try, in your controller declaration, chaging ` angular.module('UserInformationApp', [])` for  `angular.module('UserInformationApp')` ? "my flow breaking" is not an error message. you can also read the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams