# Angular Get Parameter Off URL with Slashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, routes

I am developing a single page angular app.

The app takes a token off the URL, then passes it off to an API. Currently my URL looks like this:

```
www.example.com/?token=3d2b9bc55a85b641ce867edaac8a979173d4446525230290fc86a0ed8ff18b95
```

My code is already properly using angular routes, but I have to get the token off the URL like this:

```
var postToken = $location.search().token;
```

I have this on config:

```
 app.config(function($locationProvider, $httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/token/:token', {
        templateUrl : 'views/select-token.html',
        controller : 'selectHold'
    })
    .when('/purchase-hold/token/:token', {
        templateUrl : 'views/purchase-token.html',
        controller : 'purchaseHold'
    });
});
```

I want my URL to be able to look like this:

```
www.example.com/token/3d2b9bc55a85b641ce867edaac8a979173d4446525230290fc86a0ed8ff18b95
```

What do I need to code to be able to search for a `/token/` and grab the data next to it, as opposed to `?token=`  ?

Comment: see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js

Answer (score 0):

you can inject $routeParams in your controller and it will be available in that

```
app.controller('selectToken', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     console.log($routeParams.token);
     // We now have access to the $routeParams here
});
```

then Angular will populate the $routeParams with the key of :token, and the value of key will be populated with the value of the loaded URL.

If the browser loads the URL `www.example.com/token/3d2b9bc55a85b641ce867edaac8a979173d4446525230290fc86a0ed8ff18b95`
,

then the $routeParams object will look like:

```
{ token: '3d2b9bc55a85b641ce867edaac8a979173d4446525230290fc86a0ed8ff18b95' }
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. On my .config I have `.when('/token/:token', {
  templateUrl : 'views/select-token.html',
  controller : 'selectToken'
 })`

Comment: where would I put $routeParams.token? In my config or my controller? And don't I have to change 2 things... both the config and the controller. Don't I have to change the config `when` as well as add $routeParams to my controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Build your route like you currently are

```
.when('/token/:token', {templateUrl : 'views/select-token.html', controller : 'selectToken' })
```

Then in your controller inject in $routeParams and you will be able to access your route parameter

```
.controller('selectToken', function($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.token = $routeParams.token
}
```

Comment: I had to use a fallback on my apache settings to get it to work, but now when I have www.example.com/token/3d2b9bc55a85b641ce867edaac8a979173d4446525230290fc86a0ed8ff18b95 I get a blank screen...I can see all my code via view source