# How to use $routeProvider with $_GET Parameters

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I'm new with the angularjs and I want your help. I'm trying to include the $routeProvider into my project in order to use templating system.

> ```
>      $routeProvider.when('/admin.php?page=all_transactions', {
>                 templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
>                 controller  : 'TransactionsController'
>         });
> ```

I saw that most of the examples i found the url of .when had the following format /route1/:param for urls like #/route1/12345

Because I'm using the angular in wordpress admin page I want the `.when` to work with $_GET parameters like the one I gave with the example code.
 
The depth of parameters I want it to be up to 3 and ignore any other parameters.

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it enough for u to know, that the params are there? Or do u need explicit values. 
If the params are enough u could follow this example: [URL Routing with Query Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)

```
url: "/contacts?myParam"
// will match to url of "/contacts?myParam=value"
```

If you need to have more than one, separate them with an '&':

```
url: "/contacts?myParam1&myParam2" 
// will match to url of "/contacts?myParam1=value1&myParam2=wowcool"
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: For accessing the values u can do the following: [Accessing query parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js)

> Also can get other arbitrary params in the query string form `/view/1/2?other=12` with `$routeParams.other` –  DavidC Aug 17 '14 at 21:04

OR: 
While routing is indeed a good solution for application-level URL parsing, you may want to use the more low-level $location service, as injected in your own service or controller:

```
var paramValue = $location.search().myParam;
```

This simple syntax will work for **http://example.com/path?myParam=someValue**. However, only if you configured the $locationProvider in the html5 mode before:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Otherwise have a look at the **http://example.com/#!/path?myParam=someValue** "Hashbang" syntax which is a bit more complicated, but have the benefit of working on old browsers (non-html5 compatible) as well.