# Angular js ng-model under jstl c:param value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstl

How to I see {{angularJSvalue}} under " " ? The h2 part is working fine, but I don't know how to put it under " " signs. That is what i get pussing the filter button: `...students.html?fname=%7b%7bfilterName%7d%7d`

```
<input type = "text" ng-model="filterName"/>
<h2>{{filterName}}</h2>
<a class="btn btn-default" href=
    <c:url value="students.html">
         <c:param name="fname" value="{{filterName}}"/>
    </c:url>
>Filter</a>
```

edit:
I need to keep the c:url because i want to put some of the current params in the new url

```
<input type = "text" ng-model="filterName"/>
<h2>{{filterName}}</h2>
<a class="btn btn-default" href=
    <c:url value="students.html">
         <c:param name="fname" value="{{filterName}}"/>
         <c:param name="pageNumber" value="1"/>
         <c:forEach items="${param}" var="entry">
            <c:if test="${entry.key == 'itemsOnPage'}">
                <c:param name="${entry.key}" value="${entry.value}" />
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
>Filter</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is unrelated to the value being enclosed in double quotes, but due to an incorrect understanding of the difference between client and server side.

In essence, your AngularJS `filterName` value only exists on the client, but you're trying to render it on the server using JSP (or a similar server-side technology).

The main question is: why do you need to use a server-side construct to render the URL? Why not just do it using Angular, e.g. with [`ngHref`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)?

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-href="students.html?fname={{filterName}}"/>
```

Comment: So the c:url is server side. If i get rid of it, can i modify the href based on what i have in the input field? Should I use Jquery?

Comment: i need the c:url to get the current params from url and put some of them in the a href

Comment: Why would you need `c:url` for that? There's about [a dozen ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js) to do it in Angular.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to look into it.