# Setting dynamic routes with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I want to make URL : `localhost:3000/confirm?token=TokenValue&email=emailValue`

So, I code the URL route and parameters like this

```
$stateProvider
   .state('confirm', {
      url : '/confirm?token&email',
      controller : 'ConfirmCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/validate.html
}
```

I want to get its value, so In my controller :

```
app.controller('ConfirmCtrl', function($scope, $location){
   var value = $location.search();
   console.log(value)
   var token = value.token;
   var email = value.email;
});
```

I type URL in my browser address bar to test the code like this: `localhost:3000/confirm?token=023e0938jd&email=myaddres@gmail.com`. But when the browser loads it, The URL becomes `localhost:3000/confirm`. So, I can't get the value of token and email. How do I get their value?

Comment: can you provide plunkr that reproduce your error?

Comment: you can see here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js]

Comment: I believe you need to specify parameters with notations such as `:emailID` or so.

Comment: seems your code work ok: http://plnkr.co/edit/szFE2rN3b3Iv8ui3SPih?p=preview

Comment: Thank anyway. My partner was setting the URL of the application so URL like "localhost:3000/confirm?token=TokenValue&email=emailValue can't be accepted. That the reason why the URL becomes "localhost:3000/confirm"  when it loaded.

Comment: I change my code to $stateProvider.state('/confirm/:token/:email.