# how to pass parameters into Angular2 components

Tags: angular

I have a component that renders data retrieved from the backend.  Before rendering the data needs to be filtered down based on a parameter.  The last segment of the URL is a filter value, how do I pass it down into the component?

Comment: Just look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js

Comment: that looks like Angular 1

Comment: Your question is too open ended. Do you have a code sample you are already working on?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you provide us with a code example will be easier.

Now, in your app.routes.ts you should have something like this:

```
{
  path: 'detail/:id',
  component: HeroDetailComponent
}
```

Now you will be able tou navigate to detail/11 in this case.

In detail component you need to import this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
```

and add it to the constructor as private:

```
private route: ActivatedRoute
```

Then you can get the id param like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = +params['id'];
  this.heroService.getHero(id)
    .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
});
```

In this case the hero id is a number. Route parameters are always strings. So we convert the route parameter value to a number with the JavaScript (+) operator. ***Keep that in mind.***

As mentioned [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), it will be better if you implements ngOnInit (subscribe to the params observable) and ngOnDestroy (destroy the sub)

Answer (score 0):

you can use route params in the constructor of your component

https://angular.io/guide/router

https://angular.io/api/router/Params

```
constructor(routeParams: RouteParams) {
  this.filter = routeParams.get('custom_filter');
}
```

Comment: PS: RouteParams has been deprecated for now