# How to access data from the url parameters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web, routes

So basically I'm developing a monitoring system. When I click on a specific application I want to navigate to a statistics page and load that apps stats dynamically.

So on the monitoring pages (example.com/app/#/monitorscreen) script I have the following line of code:

```
window.location = "#/applicationstats?application=" + app;
```

Which then navigates me to:

example.com/app/#/applicationstats?application=test123

My question is, how do I access the data held in the parameter 'application' above? In other words, how can I print to the screen 'test123'

Comment: inside your controller  try to console `$stateParams.application`  or `$routeParams.application`  based on which routing method you are using ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching to ng-route or better yet ui-router.
it has all the functionality you are looking for including stateParmas (accessing parameters from url)

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router

Answer (score 0):

you should use RouteProvider and RouteParams

check this answer:
[How to get the url parameters using angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 0):

In the routing file, include **$routeProvider** for ng-route  and **$stateProvider** for ui-route

```
 $routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',    
        controller: 'MyCtrl1'
    });

$stateProvider.state('partials', {
    url: '/partials/:param1/:param2',
    controller: 'MyCtrl1',
    templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html'
});
```

Then in your controller inject **$routeParams** for ng-route and **$stateParams** for ui-route:

```
.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  var param1 = $routeParams.param1;
  var param2 = $routeParams.param2; //change here from param1 to param2
  ...
}]);

.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope','$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  var param1 = $stateParams.param1;
  var param2 = $stateParams.param2; //change here from param1 to param2
  ...
}]);
```