# Get url parameters query string in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a url like this.

```
www.website.com/user.html?name=abcd
```

I want to get query string from the link on user.html page by angularjs.

I am trying to get it by location.search()

```
     var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);
        var user;
formApp.controller('formProfile1', function($scope,$http,$location){
user =$location.search().name;
        alert(user);
```

Problem is when I run above code I am getting error undefined.

Comment: Check the html5 mode, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19481865/3850821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/states)

also routing can be hell sometimes so please look at this solution.. that saved my life

https://ui-router.github.io/guide/states