# on click pass data using route in angular js

Tags: angularjs

**this is my route i want to pass id using route**

```
.state('app.profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: "assets/views/profile.html",
    resolve: loadSequence('profileCtrl'),
})
```

**my html in ng-repeat**

```
<td data-title="'Profile'">

    <nav id="cl-effect-13" class="links cl-effect-13">
         <a ui-sref="app.profile">
           <i class="ti-user"></i>
        </a>
    </nav>

</td>
```

**this is my controller hear i want to get id**

```
$scope.usersdata=function(val){

            alert(val);
        };
```

Comment: could you elaborate question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the url parameters using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angularjs)

Comment: check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller]() **How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller**